# Compare last_1d data with last_1w data in Datadog Terraform

Tags: terraform, datadog

I am using a datadog terraform to write alert monitors.
I want to compare the change in the trend of my metric in last 1 day data vs last 1 week data.
I wrote the following query for that:

```
(sum(last_1d):sum:my_metric.count{field_1:val_1} by {field_1}.as_count()) - (sum(last_1w):sum:my_metric.count{field_1:val_1} by {field_1}.as_count())/7 < 200
```

But this query is not working. It is showing invalid query.

Comment: What does `this query is not working` mean? Are there any errors? If so, add them to the question along with the terraform code you have.

Comment: It is showing invalid query